# R: Calculate p-value given Durbin Watson statistic and n

Tags: r, regression, durbin-watson-test

Given the Durbin Watson statistic, what do I need to calculate the p-value? Is there a formula I can use?

Comment: Instead of looking for a formula, try searching for a standard Durbin-Watson significance table.

Comment: Welcome ChetanMV, There are a couple of related statistics you might mean [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durbin%E2%80%93Watson_statistic). The first step is to be clear about which statistic and circumstances we're dealing with.

Comment: The function `dwtest` in the R package [lmtest](http://cran.r-project.org/package=lmtest) returns the Durbin-Watson statistic and a p-value. You may look at the source code of that function and see the part where the object `pval` is obtained.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is **NO**. Unfortuneately, the null distribution of the DW test statistic in regression analysis **depends on the design matrix $X$**. This is discussed in for instance [Seber and Lee](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/8126547286) section 10.4.4.  There is also referenced some approximate procedure, one based on upper and lower bound $D_L \le DW \le D_U$ which have distributions not depending on $X$ so can be tabled.

A modern alternative is to use simulations, the `R` package car implements this (using bootstrapping) in the function `durbinWatsonTest`.

Answer (score 0):

Critical values given n and k for .01 p
https://www.real-statistics.com/statistics-tables/durbin-watson-table/